# Classic ASP on Windows Server 2003

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2003, createobject

After I configure everything (IIS, Websites, permissions) on newly installed virtual server, I get this error when run the `default.asp` file.

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed

/default.asp, line 30
```

I found [ASP 0177](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=21069) post very useful. But I can't seem to solve it. It give a solution like this

```
A: This error means "Invalid class string" -- in other words the call to CreateObject failed because the name object cannot be found by the OLE sub-system. Causes include:

1. You really didn't run regsvr32 on the server after all.
2. You ran regsvr32 but it reported an error.
3. Someone modified security on part of the registry that's preventing the OLE subsystem from reading all or part of the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT tree.
4. The name of the object you are trying to create was mispelled or is incorrect.
5. Determine if it's a permissions problem
6. Determine if it is a file permissions problem:
7. Check registry permissions
```

Which service do I have to register? Isn't ASP automatically installed on Server 2003 when install IIS? If not what setting do I need to change? This is a freshly installed Virtual Windows Server 2003?

**EDIT**: I think this link might work but not sure [ASP Win Svr 2003](http://forums.iis.net/t/1154124.aspx)

**EDIT2**: Code:

```
Set BACSE = Server.CreateObject("NAICSCodeSE2_1_0.Engine")
If Session("DEBUG") = "TRUE" then Response.Write "BACSE Debug="&BACSE.SetDebugMode(True)&"<BR>"
```

Comment: What do you have on line 30 in default.asp? Show us the code.

Comment: What is the object you are trying to create? We need to see your code before answering..

Comment: `Set BACSE = Server.CreateObject("NAICSCodeSE2_1_0.Engine")' added in the code

Answer (score 0):

Custom COM component first need to Register in Server with below command, before using it in classic ASP page.

> regsvr32 yourcomdllfile.dll

Comment: I don't know where is the DLL

Comment: You should ask the original developer or find it in the old server which was working.

Comment: Old server crashed and the old developer has left too.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter You can use that script to getting dll location with passing CLSID as a parameter. (`NAICSCodeSE2_1_0.Engine`) http://support.softartisans.com/kbview_1294.aspx